# How can I send data to aws lambda via aws gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, xmlhttprequest, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I just started to study aws lambda & gateway and now I'm trying to make a simple API with aws Lambda.

This is my lambda function.

```
'use strict'
console.log('Loading event');

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
var name = (event.name === undefined? 'No-Name' : event.name);
callback(null, {"Your-name" : name}); // SUCCESS with message
};
```

This is my mapping template.(Content-Type : application/json)

```
{"name" : "$input.params('name')"}
```

I want to change the value of name, so I tried,

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'my api url...');
xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
       console.log(xhr.response);
   }
};
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.responseType = 'json';
var name = "JACK";
xhr.send(name);
```

It doesn't work. 
I want something like {"Your-name" : "JACK"} but it only returns {"Your-name" : "No-Name"}.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: it was a stupid mistake. 
I had to use 'POST', not 'GET'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try:

```js
var json = JSON.stringify({ name: "JACK" });
xhr.send(json);
```

?

Comment: The input format of lambda function must be JSON, that's why it doesn't work. I can't send JSON object with XMLhttprequest, so I'm trying to use mapping template in integration request.. but nothing is easy for me haha

Comment: Put a console.log(JSON.stringify(event, null, 2)) in your handler, make the request again and see what's inside the event object.

Comment: oh it works !! Thanks, Tom Melo. My mistake was a really stupid thing.